# How does an event handler queue

Tags: c#, .net, events

How do event handlers queue or buffer? If you call a method in your event handler and the program receives a lot of event hits will that interfere with the method? sync and async?

i tried to create a little script in winforms where my button is my event handler and a method that just do thread.sleep(x). tried sync and async. for example:

```
public override OnChanged(object obj)
{
    Call method();
}

public void method()
{
   //do something 
}
```

So in this example what happens when i trigger 2 events on the same time from different classes. how do they buffer? Coz if event 1 is calling the method and takes some time I guess in sync event 2 has to wait untill event 1 is completed? Is this true?

When using async I assume everything will start at the same time but it will probably have a buffer also? Is this true?

And in both cases is there a possibility that when hit with multiple events at the same time my method could be scrambled with information from event 1 and 2. If yes how can I avoid it?

Comment: I am also looking for answers to the above question. Technology Researcher, did you find any answers?

Comment: no not yet, altought if you have purly event you can use azure event hub I guess.

Comment: I asked a question to get answers. Here's the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76563609/does-c-sharp-maintain-queue-for-events/. Maybe this helps.